# React Native: Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact(componentIdentifier=com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0)

Tags: android, react-native

I tried to run the react-native app on android studio, but it's throwing an error.
The app is working fine on an iOS device.

> Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact(componentIdentifier=com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0, variantName=null, artifactFile=/Users/krishna/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.71.0-rc.0/7a7f5a0af6ebd8eb94f7e5f7495e9d9684b4f543/react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar, extractedFolder=null, dependencyType=ANDROID, isWrappedModule=false, buildMapping={**current_build**=/Users/krishna/Documents/Projects/ANTIJOURNAL/android}, mavenCoordinatesCache=com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.MavenCoordinatesCacheBuildService$Inject@7350d5fe)

Here is my app/build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.5.0'

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
}

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
}

if (enableHermes) {
    def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
    debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
    releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
} else {
    implementation jscFlavor
}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

in gradle.properties file replace with this line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
    // ...

    if (enableHermes) {
       implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+") {
           exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
       }
       def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
       debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
       releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue.
I have removed and re-copied the aar file into libs folder.
And I have removed the aar file in the project structure -> dependencies -> under modules and added the same.
After that I have synched and its successfully synched.